# Align Pivot Header items in Center of the Page

Tags: xaml, pivot, uwp, uwp-xaml

I am using Pivot control in my UWP application. The problem is that Pivot aligns its Header items on the left side of the page. Is it possible to align them in the center of the page? I have tried this with custom style for PivotItemHeader, but it didn't work out. My style is shown below.

```
<Style TargetType="PivotHeaderItem">
        <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="{ThemeResource PivotHeaderItemFontSize}" />
        <Setter Property="FontFamily" Value="{ThemeResource PivotHeaderItemFontFamily}" />
        <Setter Property="FontWeight" Value="{ThemeResource PivotHeaderItemThemeFontWeight}" />
        <Setter Property="CharacterSpacing" Value="{ThemeResource PivotHeaderItemCharacterSpacing}" />
        <Setter Property="Background" Value="Transparent" />
        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Gray" />
        <!-- original value {ThemeResource SystemControlForegroundBaseMediumBrush} -->
        <Setter Property="Padding" Value="{ThemeResource PivotHeaderItemMargin}" />
        <Setter Property="Height" Value="48" />
        <Setter Property="VerticalContentAlignment" Value="Center" />
        <Setter Property="IsTabStop" Value="False" />
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="PivotHeaderItem">
                    <Grid x:Name="Grid" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}">
                        <Grid.Resources>
                            <Style x:Key="BaseContentPresenterStyle" TargetType="ContentPresenter">
                                <Setter Property="FontFamily" Value="Segoe UI" />
                                <Setter Property="FontWeight" Value="SemiBold" />
                                <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="15" />

                                <Setter Property="TextWrapping" Value="Wrap" />
                                <Setter Property="LineStackingStrategy" Value="MaxHeight" />
                                <Setter Property="TextLineBounds" Value="Full" />
                                <Setter Property="OpticalMarginAlignment" Value="TrimSideBearings" />
                            </Style>
                            <Style x:Key="BodyContentPresenterStyle" TargetType="ContentPresenter" BasedOn="{StaticResource BaseContentPresenterStyle}">
                                <Setter Property="FontFamily" Value="{ThemeResource PivotHeaderItemFontFamily}" />
                                <Setter Property="FontWeight" Value="{ThemeResource PivotHeaderItemThemeFontWeight}" />
                                <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="{ThemeResource PivotHeaderItemFontSize}" />

                            </Style>
                        </Grid.Resources>
                        <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                            <VisualStateGroup x:Name="SelectionStates">
                                <VisualStateGroup.Transitions>
                                    <VisualTransition From="Unselected" To="UnselectedLocked" GeneratedDuration="0:0:0.33" />
                                    <VisualTransition From="UnselectedLocked" To="Unselected" GeneratedDuration="0:0:0.33" />
                                </VisualStateGroup.Transitions>
                                <VisualState x:Name="Disabled">
                                    <Storyboard>
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="ContentPresenter" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource SystemControlDisabledBaseMediumLowBrush}" />
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    </Storyboard>
                                </VisualState>
                                <VisualState x:Name="Unselected" />
                                <VisualState x:Name="UnselectedLocked">
                                    <Storyboard>
                                        <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="ContentPresenterTranslateTransform" Storyboard.TargetProperty="X" Duration="0" To="{ThemeResource PivotHeaderItemLockedTranslation}" />
                                        <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="ContentPresenter" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.Opacity)" Duration="0" To="0" />
                                    </Storyboard>
                                </VisualState>
                                <VisualState x:Name="Selected">
                                    <Storyboard>
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="ContentPresenter" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{StaticResource currentThemeColor}" />
                                            <!-- original value {ThemeResource SystemControlHighlightAltBaseHighBrush} -->
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="Grid" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Background">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource SystemControlHighlightTransparentBrush}" />
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    </Storyboard>
                                </VisualState>
                                <VisualState x:Name="UnselectedPointerOver">
                                    <Storyboard>
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="ContentPresenter" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource SystemControlHighlightAltBaseMediumHighBrush}" />
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="Grid" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Background">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource SystemControlHighlightTransparentBrush}" />
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    </Storyboard>
                                </VisualState>
                                <VisualState x:Name="SelectedPointerOver">
                                    <Storyboard>
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="ContentPresenter" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource SystemControlHighlightAltBaseMediumHighBrush}" />
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="Grid" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Background">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource SystemControlHighlightTransparentBrush}" />
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    </Storyboard>
                                </VisualState>
                                <VisualState x:Name="UnselectedPressed">
                                    <Storyboard>
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="ContentPresenter" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource SystemControlHighlightAltBaseMediumHighBrush}" />
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="Grid" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Background">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource SystemControlHighlightTransparentBrush}" />
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    </Storyboard>
                                </VisualState>
                                <VisualState x:Name="SelectedPressed">
                                    <Storyboard>
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="ContentPresenter" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource SystemControlHighlightAltBaseMediumHighBrush}" />
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="Grid" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Background">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource SystemControlHighlightTransparentBrush}" />
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    </Storyboard>
                                </VisualState>
                            </VisualStateGroup>
                        </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                        <ContentPresenter x:Name="ContentPresenter" Content="{TemplateBinding Content}" ContentTemplate="{TemplateBinding ContentTemplate}" Margin="{TemplateBinding Padding}" FontSize="{TemplateBinding FontSize}" FontFamily="{TemplateBinding FontFamily}" FontWeight="{TemplateBinding FontWeight}" HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}" VerticalAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}">
                            <ContentPresenter.RenderTransform>
                                <TranslateTransform x:Name="ContentPresenterTranslateTransform" />
                            </ContentPresenter.RenderTransform>
                        </ContentPresenter>
                    </Grid>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
```

Comment: Did you try setting `HorizontalContentAlignment` to `center`

Comment: Yes, I tried putting it on Pivot item, and in style above as one of its setters for TargetType="PivotHeaderItem"

Comment: I see where you set `VerticalContentAlignment` but not `HorizontalContentAlignment` in your setters. Your snippet looks pretty default overall.

Comment: @ChrisW. I tried adding setter for HorizontalContentAlignment and setting it to center, but it didn't help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If I understood you correctly, you want to center all the headers. If so, then you don't want to change *PivotHeaderItem*, [but *Pivot's* style](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/mt299144.aspx). There you will find something like *HeaderClipper*, change its default *HorizontalContentAlignment* from *Stretch* to *Center* and it should work:

```xml
<!-- some code before -->
<ContentControl x:Name="HeaderClipper" Grid.Column="1" HorizontalContentAlignment="Center" UseSystemFocusVisuals="True">
<!-- some code before -->
```